# Migrating from Android API23 to API24

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, dependencies

Currently I'm targetting API23 with minimum 14.

I've tried changing this to API24 in the build.gradle, then changing Build Tools to version 24.0.0
and changing the `JDK 1.7` location in settings to the `JDK 1.8` that I downloaded. I always get problems about dex files and `heap size`.
So I tried increasing the heap size and enabling/disabling `multidex` or `dexInProcess`...

Nothing helped.

I thought this would be much easier to do, so does anybody have any suggestions what I'm missing?

Comment: if u dont need to whole package of play-services dont use ,, this package cuases a lot of multidex problems and conflicts google divded the packages so you can only use what needed.

Comment: that's exactly what I said I want to do. I have the separate package for everything I need but also the `play-services:8.4.0` general package so I want to remove it and add just the `firebase-messaging` one. However, when I do, GoogleApiClient class cannot be recognised. So I'm asking, which package contains the `GoogleApiClient`

Comment: old versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services or com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm

Comment: i'm not sure you understand me, GoogleApiClient is not deprecated and is part of the latest packages too. Nevermind, the error was in the fact that I was using one package with version 8.4 and firebase was 9.2 so that difference gave me errors. I edited my question so that it is now only about the migration from Api23 to 24.

Comment: Kindly post the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: It seems the problems with `heap size` etc were probably mixed with my other problem I discussed in the comments above. Since I already fixed it, I tried changing numbers in the `build gradle` and the app *compiled* fine this time for `API 24`. I still got some kind of error in the bottom bar of Android Studio when I tried to change the `build tools` from the GUI but I ignored it and did it myself in the `build.gradle` and it's fine now!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your android studio to version 2.1.1 or new beta builds . Because api 24 is designed to work with jdk8